# Double array pointers in CIL

Tags: c#, pointers, cil

I'm playing around with CIL code and pointers and so far I understand it, but there is something odd.
Consider this C# code:

```
double* a = stackalloc double[3];   
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
```

Using LINQPad I get this IL code for the assigning of the variables:

```
IL_000C:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_000D:  ldc.i4.8    
IL_000E:  conv.i      
IL_000F:  add         
IL_0010:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 
IL_0019:  stind.r8    

IL_001A:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_001B:  ldc.i4.s    10 
IL_001D:  conv.i      
IL_001E:  add         
IL_001F:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 08 40 
IL_0028:  stind.r8
```

The first time it adds 8 to the pointer which I assume is the length of a double (8bytes) to get to index 1.
But the second time it adds 10, which does not make sense to me. Can anyone explain to my why it uses 10?
Thank you.

Comment: @JamesBarrass oh dear... that makes sense. and 0x18 is 24 for index 3... Thank you!

Comment: @JohannesB C# *and* pointers?

Comment: @Thomas yes if you believe it or not there are cases (however rare) where it is useful

Comment: @JohannesB I know, but good luck :)

Comment: @Thomas good :) too many people bash on pointers too quickly. Thank you, I might need it ^^

Answer (score 0):

As [James Barrass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278352/double-array-pointers-in-cil#comment46754746_29278352) correctly pointed out, the values shown by ildasm are in hex. `10` means 0x10 = 16.